# JavaScript widget won't work for my website

Tags: javascript, html, widget, closures

I am a blogger and I am trying to upload a widget on my website, I've taken the widget's code from [here](http://www.momondo.com/content/programmes/flightwidget/)

As far as I understand the concept I just have to copy/paste the code in my HTML. Sadly, it doesnt work this way.

I though that it migh be in conflict with some of the code on my site, so I tested it in an empty HTML file, but again it wouldn't work.

I put the code in a snippet and I hope someone can have a look at it, so I know where is the problem.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>momondo flight widget</title>
</head>
<body>

 <div id="mmd-flight-widget"></div> 
<script type="text/javascript">(function initWidget() {
 var options = { 
  layout: { 
   theme: "momondo"
   , width: "300" 
   , height: "250" 
  },     
  airports: {   
   origin: "LON", 
   destination: "PAR" 
  },     
  settings: {   
   openNewWindow: true, 
   domain: "www.momondo.com",  
   source: ""   
  }        
 };         
 var settings = options.settings; 
 var airports = options.airports; 
 var layout = options.layout;  
 var encoding = null;    
 onWidgetLoad = function (f)   
 {         
  f("mmd-flight-widget", {  
   searchForms: [{    
    type: 1,    
    searchURL: "http://[DOMAIN][PATH][QUERY]" + (!!settings.source ? "&source=" + settings.source : ""), 
    openNewWindow: settings.openNewWindow,    
    currency: settings.currency,      
    segments: [           
     {            
      airports: [         
       { code: airports.origin || "" },  
       { code: airports.destination || "" } 
      ]           
     },            
     {            
      airports: [         
       { code: airports.destination || "" }, 
       { code: airports.origin || "" }    
      ] 
     }  
    ]   
   }]    
  });     
 };      
 var scr = document.createElement("script");
 scr["src"] = "http://" + settings.domain + "/widget/searchform/v1.0/?dimensions=" + (layout.width && layout.height ? (layout.width + "x" + layout.height) : "generic") + "&types=1&callback=onWidgetLoad&theme=" + layout.theme; 
 var tag = document.getElementsByTagName("head"); 
 if (tag && tag.length)  
 {       
  tag = tag[0];   
  tag.appendChild(scr); 
 }       
})();
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the url value for `scr["src"]` to use https: seems to do the trick

```
scr["src"] = "https://" + settings.domain + ...
```

Here's a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scnhjeeq/)

Comment: Nothings happens when I try to run the snippet. Are you sure it is working?

Comment: Have you checked the fiddle I provided? It works. It won't work in a S/O snippet though ... I tried adding one to my answer and had the same issue as you. I think it has to do with some kind of sandboxing effect here on S/O, because the code runs fine in the fiddle I provided.

Comment: thanks, @trevor, this made it work. Do you know why though it wouldnt work with http, but just with https

Comment: @user1866925 - The error that shows up on jsfiddle.net when you try using plain http for the src is: Mixed Content: The page at 'https://jsfiddle.net/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://www.momondo.com/widget/searchform/v1.0/?dimensions=300x250&types=1&callback=onWidgetLoad&theme=momondo'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

If you switch back to plain http on your site and check the console window you may see the same error. It seems that the site providing this code should update it to always use https for the src url.